# EMR 5.x | Spark on Yarn | Exit code 137 and Java heap space Error

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

I have been getting this error `Container exited with a non-zero exit code 137` while running spark on yarn. I have tried couple of techniques after going through but didnt help. The spark configurations looks like below:

```
spark.driver.memory 10G
spark.driver.maxResultSize  2G
spark.memory.fraction   0.8
```

I am using yarn in client mode. `spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-redshift_2.10:0.5.0 --jars RedshiftJDBC4-1.2.1.1001.jar elevatedailyjob.py > log5.out 2>&1 &`

The sample code :

```
# Load the file (its a single file of 3.2GB)

my_df = spark.read.csv('s3://bucket-name/path/file_additional.txt.gz', schema=MySchema, sep=';', header=True)

# write the de_pulse_ip data into parquet format
my_df = my_df.select("ip_start","ip_end","country_code","region_code","city_code","ip_start_int","ip_end_int","postal_code").repartition(50)
my_df.write.parquet("s3://analyst-adhoc/elevate/tempData/de_pulse_ip1.parquet", mode = "overwrite")

# read my_df data intp dataframe from parquet files
my_df1 = spark.read.parquet("s3://bucket-name/path/my_df.parquet").repartition("ip_start_int","ip_end_int")

#join with another dataset 200 MB
my_df2 = my_df.join(my_df1, [my_df.ip_int_cast > my_df1.ip_start_int,my_df.ip_int_cast <= my_df1.ip_end_int], how='right')
```

Note: the input file is a single gzip file. It's unzipped size is 3.2GB

Comment: how many executors do you have? how much RAM did you allocate for each executor? What is the size of the unzipped input file?

Comment: the unzipped file is 3.2 GB. for allocating RAM, i tried few options 1. I did not do any memory and just used the default 2. then I used  6GB for each executor but it still fails.

Comment: How many executor with 6GB RAM did you use?

Answer (score 13):

Here is the solution for the above issues.

exit code 137 and Java heap space Error is mainly related to memory w.r.t the executors and the driver. Here is something I have done

- to increase the driver memory `spark.driver.memory   16G`  increase
- the storage memory `fraction spark.storage.memoryFraction   0.8`
- increase the executor memory `spark.executor.memory 3G`

One very important thing I would like to share which actually made a huge impact in performance is something like below:

As I mentioned above I have a single file (.csv and gzip of 3.2GB) which after unzipping becomes 11.6 GB. 
To load gzip files, spark always starts a single executor(for each .gzip file) as it can not parallelize (even if you increase partitions) as gzip files are not splittable. this hampers the whole performance as spark first read the whole file (using one executor) into the master ( I am running spark-submit in client mode) and then uncompress it and then repartitions (if mentioned to re-partition).

To address this, I used s3-dist-cp command and moved the file from s3 to hdfs and also reduced the block size so as to increase the parallelism. something like below

```
/usr/bin/s3-dist-cp --src=s3://bucket-name/path/ --dest=/dest_path/  --groupBy='.*(additional).*'  --targetSize=64 --outputCodec=none
```

although, it takes little time to move the data from s3 to HDFS, the overall performance of the process increases significantly.